# Convert 0d array to 1d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

The problem is:

```
c1Factors=[]
for i in range(1,maxFactor+1):
    if maxFactor%i==0:
       c1Factors.append(i)

print ("Factors of {} = {}".format(num,c1Factors))

#x is the 1D numpy array
x = np.array([1,10,20,40,50,70,80,90,120])
```

The output or the factor example: Factors of 122 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, ...]
The c1Factors is the 0D array
I want to convert it like the 1D numpy array

Comment: `np.array(c1Factors)`?

Comment: Paul H, ValueError Traceback (most recent call last) - Error

Comment: you're going to have edit the question to include more information

Comment: I don't see a 0D array anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me given whatever you have written. Also note that the `0d array` you are talking about is called a python `list`. I think you have mistakenly written the factors list for `122` in the question as well!

```py
import numpy as np

maxFactor = 122
c1Factors=[]
for i in range(1,maxFactor+1):
        if maxFactor%i==0:
           c1Factors.append(i)

c = np.array(c1Factors)
```

`c` becomes

```
array([  1,   2,  61, 122])
```